# Does Prim's algorithm checks graph connectivity by itself?

Tags: graph-algorithm, greedy, prims-algorithm

I have some questions.

1.do we have to check the graph's connectivity before passing it to prim's Algorithm or the the algorithm can take care of that?

2. Does prim's algorithm always work correctly on negative edge weights?
3. How can I use prim's algorithm to find spanning tree with no weights on its edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) I believe the purpose of Prim's algorithm is to 'generate' a minimum spanning tree with the nodes that you give it. I suppose you do need to make sure that an edge does exist between any 2 nodes that you give it.

2.) Prim's algorithm (and minimum spanning tree algorithms) should work correctly on negative edge weights

3.) I don't think so. I suppose you could make all of them '1' or something, but I don't think that would result in a very meaningful minimum spanning tree.

Comment: can you give reasons why prim's algorithm works correctly on negative edges?

Comment: I would disagree about (3) , you can use Prims to find a spanning tree on an equally (or zero) weighted graph. It isn't the minimum but it is a spanning tree as the op asked.

Comment: I guess you could think of it like this: The objective of the minimum spanning tree is to construct such a tree with the minimum possible sum for the edges. 

Let our smallest edge be -k. If we add k to all of our edges, then none of them will be negative. We can then conduct our MST like normal. We can then subtract k * (V - 1)  from the sum, to find the original sum. (V is the number of nodes.) 

V - 1 appears because it is a tree, and that is the number of edges that the tree has.

Comment: **The reason why negative edges doesn't work in Dijkstra's is because we may have a 'varying number' of edges. However, in a MST, we always know that there will be exactly V-1 edges, and as a result, negatives don't matter. (Not a formal proof, but just my intuitive mindset)